# How do I Rotate 2D Player Using Buttons in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

So I'm trying to create a birds-eye shooter game in Unity2D but I can't get my player to rotate with the A&D keys. Anyone have any ideas?

I tried adding my custom variable (float rotateSpeed = 5f;) to my players rotation but it says (Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Quaternion' and 'float') I don't know what else to try

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Quaternions to rotate your 2D sprite, try using [Transform.rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) like so:

```
void TurnLeft() {
    transform.Rotate(0,0,rotateSpeed);
}

void TurnRight() {
    transform.Rotate(0,0,-rotateSpeed);
}
```

Now whenever you trigger either function, it will rotate your sprite by that amount in either direction. A positive speed rotates your sprite left, and a negative speed rotates right.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a `horizontalInput` variable and to multiply itself by your rotationSpeed, like this:

```
private float horizontalInput;
[SerializeField] private float speed = 5.0f;

void Update()
{
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    // Rotate(x,y,z)
    transform.Rotate(0, horizontalInput * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```